# Thymeleaf + spring dynamic replace

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Is it possible to create a dynamic replace in Thymeleaf?

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("template","login");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And the following view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head></head>
<body>

<div th:replace="fragments/${template} :: ${template}"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
Error resolving template "fragments/${template}", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to preprocess my variables like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/${__#{${template}}__} :: ${__#{${template}}__}"></div>
```

How ever now `${template}` is getting replaced with `login` i have the following error now:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "??login_en_US??"
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I would try placing the text in a single quote like so: `th:replace="'fragments/' + ${template} + '::'  + ${template}"`

Comment: @JoeEssey thanks for your comment. It is possible to do String concatenation how ever without the preprocessing it will be: fragments/${template}...

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a hierarchical layout approach, like Tiles or SiteMesh. Thymeleaf does offer this functionality. It is documented in this article: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html. See the section 'Thymeleaf Layout Dialect.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the appropriate method to manage this behavior in thymeleaf is to use `layout:fragment` tags.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Here is a simple example of my layout page, and the login page which is 'dynamically' loaded:

layout.html

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">Layout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div th:fragment="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div th:fragment="script"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, when login gets loaded, it replaces the `th:fragment` div with the associated div in the html view which matches the string returned by the controller method, in this case login.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="content">
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if you want to load another fragment conditionally, the approach I take is to add replace tags with th:if cases.  Here's an example of a Form that displays different questions based on an attribute of the current user:

```
<div th:if="${foo.type)} == 'type_1'">
    <div th:replace="fragments/custom-questions :: type-1-checkboxes"></div>
</div>
<div th:if="${foo.type} == 'type_2'">
    <div th:replace="fragments/custom-questions :: type-2-checkboxes"></div>
</div>
```

Then the associated div gets loaded from the file custom-questions.html:

```
<div th:fragment="type-1-checkboxes">
  //stuff
</div>

<div th:fragment="type-2-checkboxes">
  //stuff
</div>
```

Comment: I have a solution i don't know that this is a good practice though:
<div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${template}} :: ${template}"></div>

Comment: Your string interpolation is a very cool solution.  I am just starting with thymeleaf after moving from erb, so I'm excited to learn the tricks.

Comment: Same situation here :)

Answer (score 18):

Although Joe Essey's solution is working as well i solved with following code:

```
<div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${template}} :: ${template}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am just encountering this issue (this is my first time with thymeleaf/spring). This is what solved it for me:

```
<div class="col-md-12" th:include="__${template}__ :: body" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In Thymeleaf 3.0, the following solution has worked for me:

```
<div th:replace="('fragments/' + ${template}) :: (${template})">
```

(Note however, that I use it with fixed name of the fragment and dynamic name of the template, so the parantheses around  `:: (${template})` might be optional.)

The solution is inspired by documentation for Thymeleaf in https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fragment-specification-syntax

> Both templatename and selector in the above examples can be fully-featured expressions (even conditionals!) like:
> `<div th:insert="footer :: (${user.isAdmin}? #{footer.admin} : #{footer.normaluser})"></div>`
> Note again how the surrounding ~{...} envelope is optional in th:insert/th:replace

Answer (score 1):

```
<div th:insert=“${subpage}::fragementName”>
```

Just change  subpage names and you will dynamic behaviour in thymleaf

Comment: <div th:include=‘${subpage}::fragmentName'>